# Как сделать таймер который будет показываться на экране?(python turtle)

Tags: python, таймер, turtle

Как сделать таймер который будет показываться на экране в краю и после его окончания сработает следующая команда? Я школьник, попросили сделать игру. Я сделал игру про решение примеров на время, с примерами я разобрался, а с таймером нет. Таймер должен считаться с 15 до 1 секунды. Если время закончилось то будет писаться на экране “nope”. Я искал ответ во многих местах но не нашел таймер который показывается на экране.

Comment: Добавьте больше информации, свои соображения по этому поводу, что уже пробовали реализовать, где застряли, может наброски кода уже есть, ошибки? что-нибудь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого таймера наверное нет. Но вы его можете создать сами.

```
from time import sleep
sleep(время в секундах)
```

Но он будет задерживать всю программу, поэтому с помощью модуля Thread сделайте новый параллельный поток, в котором и будет sleep.

```
def func():
    x = 15
    # вывод х на экран
    for i in range(15):
        sleep(1)
        x -= 1
        # вывод х на экран
Thread.start_new_thread(func, ())
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Thread'`

Comment: У вас модуль не установлен.В командной строке напишите: pip install Thread.Если у вас выдалась ошибка или модуль не установился, то загуглите так: установка модулей.И посмотрите пару уроков про это